# Codeigniter curl how to send CSRF token?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I'm having trouble filling a form on another page with curl. How to download and insert CSRF token in Codeigniter? Without using CSRF, the form is added without any problem. CSRF looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_test_name" value="795e736ebd33938c7371e50b2085f6d7" />
```

And my entire curl code looks like this

```
$curl_connection = 
  curl_init('http://localhost/form');
 curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
 curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 
  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, APPPATH . '/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, APPPATH . '/cookies.txt');


$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($result);
  $token = $doc->getElementById("csrf_test_name")->attributes->getNamedItem("value")->value;

  $post_data['title'] = 'Myname';
  $post_data['csrf_test_name'] = $token;
  $post_data['email'] = 'my@email.com';


foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' . 
curl_error($curl_connection);


curl_close($curl_connection);
    }
```

I am a beginner in the topic of curl, can anyone help me how to read this csrf? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You are getting CSRF token as a POST field and setting post fields with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS already, what kind of error / result do you get?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getNamedItem() on null

Comment: Oh, it seems like this is not curl problem, you are just not getting the value of the field ( $token ) correctly.

Comment: @Adem Tepe ok, but how to get it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this, working:

**First of all, you need to change name to id:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="csrf_test_name" value="795e736ebd33938c7371e50b2085f6d7" />
```

Because you are using `getElementById("csrf_test_name")`.

**Secondly, you need to get the attribute value like this:**

```
$token = $doc->getElementById("csrf_test_name")->getAttribute('value');
```

You should be fine unless there is another error.

**P.S.** You have used here PHP XML DOM Parser but usually for this kind job [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm) is used. Why? Because we are parsing HTML :)

If the data were XML, then we would be talking about nodes and we could get the value in a more clear way like this:

```
$token = $doc->getElementById("csrf_test_name")->nodeValue;
```

Comment: @adam Tepe Thanks for your help now it works. But now I have another problem. The form is filled in with text data, but this form also includes uploading photos as a second form. Upload is done with Ajax. And I don't know how to upload photos.

Comment: I don't know if you can make an AJAX call with cURL because AJAX call is made with javascript.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48214437/send-ajax-request-through-curl